# how to case white outline on an image in css?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a png image of a person's head when I hover on it I want the head to get white outline about `5px` I tried to use:

```css
imgOnHover: {
  filter: 'drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #FFF)',
},
```

but it is kind of faded and it comes from one side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various properties for this:

```
border: 1px solid #fff;

filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px 5px #FFF);
```

Target your image in `css` and then add either of these to see if it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img:hover {
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img:hover {
  outline: 5px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```css
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px 5px #FFF);
```

Unfortunately! `spread-radius` thus `5px` are not widely supported now.[See the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow)